# What is meant by not generating the answer lazily in this code?

Tags: scala

I came across the following code:

```
/*
  Unlike `take`, `drop` is not incremental. That is, it doesn't generate the
  answer lazily. It must traverse the first `n` elements of the stream eagerly.
*/
@annotation.tailrec
final def drop(n: Int): Stream[A] = this match {
  case Cons(_, t) if n > 0 => t().drop(n - 1)
  case _ => this
}

/*
  `take` first checks if n==0. In that case we need not look at the stream at all.
*/
def take(n: Int): Stream[A] = this match {
  case Cons(h, t) if n > 1 => cons(h(), t().take(n - 1))
  case Cons(h, _) if n == 1 => cons(h(), empty)
  case _ => empty
}
```

Could someone explain what is meant by the comment:

> Unlike `take`, `drop` is not incremental. That is, it doesn't generate the
>         answer lazily. It must traverse the first `n` elements of the stream eagerly.

To me, it looks like both the `drop` and `take` functions have to traverse the first n elements of the stream eagerly? What is it about the `drop` function that causes the first n elements to be eagerly traversed?

(Full code context here: https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for `Cons` is:

```
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

Notice that the second parameter, `t`, takes a function (from Unit to Stream[A]), not the evaluation of that function. This is not evaluated until required, and hence is lazy, as is the `take` method that calls it.

Compare this to `drop` which calls `t()` itself rather than passing it into the `Cons`, forcing the immediate evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that `cons` is lazy. That is if the recursion is inside of `cons`, the recursion won't happen until the tail of the generated list is actually accessed. Whereas if the recursion is outside, it happens right away.

So `drop` is eager because the recursion is not inside a `cons` (or any other lazy construct).